# emery cloth or sandpaper to remove corrosion

Tags: plumbing, valve, corrosion

I'm considering to replace a stop-and-waste valve in the basement, where copper pipes are installed. So I need to clean the corrosion off the pipe. My question is if I could use fine-grained sandpaper instead of emery cloth (since I see it is normally recommended), is there a big difference between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: I've used coarse steel wool, and 3m sanding mats in a pinch. Just about anything abrasive would work IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Emery cloth is better able to handle moisture and repeated flex due to scrubbing. Otherwise, they'll both do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  I have used a flat blade screwdriver as a scraper to remove the worst corrosion.  In a pinch that was sufficient to revive a dead car.  Also, I used the same technique to rejoin some copper pipe where a joint failed from bad soldering and I didn't have any 220 grit sandpaper to do a better job under duress.